# Spritkit : Detect collision while drawing line using finger

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I am trying to detect collision `contactPoint` between `existing line` and line which user `currently drawing using finger`.

Here is my code :

```
let padding: CGFloat = 100
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    let startPoint1 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + padding , y: self.frame.minY + padding)
    let leftHorizontalPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + padding, y: self.frame.maxY - padding)

    let line1 = SKShapeNode()
    let line_path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    line_path.move(to: startPoint1)
    line_path.addLine(to: leftHorizontalPoint)
    line1.path = line_path
    line1.lineWidth = 3
    line1.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    addChild(line1)

    line1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: line1.frame)
    line1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    line1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.solidLine
    line1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.currentLine
    line1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.currentLine
}
```

Then on touchBegin, touchMove & touchEnd I am having following code :

```
var currentLineNode: SKShapeNode!
var startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    startPoint = pos
}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if currentLineNode != nil {
        currentLineNode.removeFromParent()
    }
    currentLineNode = SKShapeNode()
    currentLineNode.zPosition = 1
    let line_path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    line_path.move(to: startPoint)
    line_path.addLine(to: pos)
    currentLineNode.path = line_path
    currentLineNode.lineWidth = 3
    currentLineNode.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    addChild(currentLineNode)

    currentLineNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: currentLineNode.frame)
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.currentLine
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.solidLine
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.solidLine
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if currentLineNode != nil {
        currentLineNode.removeFromParent()
    }
    currentLineNode = SKShapeNode()
    let line_path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    line_path.move(to: startPoint)
    line_path.addLine(to: pos)
    currentLineNode.path = line_path
    currentLineNode.lineWidth = 3
    currentLineNode.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    addChild(currentLineNode)

    currentLineNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: currentLineNode.frame)
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.currentLine
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.solidLine
    currentLineNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.solidLine
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}
```

`physicsWorld's contactDelegate` as follow : (Delegate not even executed)

```
extension GameScene : SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
       // This never get detected :(
       print(contact.contactPoint)
       var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
       var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
       if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
           firstBody = contact.bodyA
           secondBody = contact.bodyB
       } else {
           firstBody = contact.bodyB
           secondBody = contact.bodyA
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my output where even though passing from white colored line its not detecting collision.

[image]

What could be wrong? Any suggestion on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating your physics body with an edge loop. Apple defines edge loops as...

> An edge has no volume or mass and is always treated as if the isDynamic property is equal to false. Edges may only collide with volume-based physics bodies.

changing your physics body to this works

```
currentLineNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: currentLineNode.frame.size, center: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + currentLineNode.frame.size.width / 2, y: startPoint.y + currentLineNode.frame.size.height / 2))
```

also should be noted that changing your physics body in touchesEnded is redundant and adds nothing. I removed it from touchesEnded and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 edge based bodies.  Edge based bodies will always be `isDynamic = false` no matter if you set it or not.  You need at least 1 volume based body to be able to perform a contact.

Plus on top of that you are constantly removing and adding a node, which is a terrible idea.

I would recommend adding your node on the touchesBegan only, then update only the path on touchesMoved

Comment: damn, beat me to it